# Error:java: error: release version 5 not supported

Tags: java, intellij-idea, компиляция

Такая проблем уже не впервые, не помню как  получилось решить, вроде бы новый проект создавал. 
Крч есть класс, есть метод `main()` и есть `System.out.println("Hello");`
При вызове мейна выбивает ошибку компиляции и `Error:java: error: release version 5 not supported`
В чём может быть проблема и как её решить?

Проблемный метод:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

Скрин настроек проекта:
[image: настройки проекта]

Comment: Насколько мне известно, в Java нет такого метода, как sout. Обычно в некоторых средах данная аббревиатура используется для того, чтобы редактор сам подставил System.out.println

Comment: Извините, я просто сократил. В Inteliij Idea при вводе комбинации sout прописывается System.out.println().

Comment: В таком случае продемонстрируйте минимальный готовый пример, которые генерирует подобную ошибку.

Comment: @ImmRaytal, покажите что у вас в настройках проекта в IDE - возможно там стоит, собственно, 5 версия Явы и потому оно и не пашет. Коли так - то там можно её поменять на 8+ и всё должно заработать.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб , шапку обновил

Comment: @ImmRaytal, а пробовали на 8 версию переключить?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб , всё прекрасно работало на 11, тем более не очень хочется качать jdk. Не думаю, что проблема в этом

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Если используете IntelijIDEA, то внимательно проверяйте, что у Вас настроено в *Project Structure*:

```
Project Structure >> Project >> Project SDK;
Project Structure >> Project >> Project language level;
Project Structure >> Modules >> Dependencies >> Module SDK;
Project Structure >> Modules >> Sources;
Project Structure >> SDKs;
```

Потому что ошибка `java: error: release version 5 not supported` может возникать, когда версия компилятора в настройках IDE:

```
File >> Settings >> Build, Execution, Deployment >> Compiler >> Java Compiler >> project bytecode version >> Per-module bytecode version
```

не совпадает с той, что указана в *Project Structure*.

Кроме того, если Вы собираете Jar и успешно сбилдили артефакты, проверьте, чтобы в *Run/Debug Configurations* версия JRE по дефолту также соответствовала версии проекта.

Если используете сборщик Maven, то можете с помощью POM изменить явно версию проекта, написав такие строчки:

```
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
```

Или же в плагине:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

*Иногда настройки в Project Structure и версия компилятора могут сбиваться, поэтому перед очередной сборкой проверяйте, чтобы всё соответствовало Вашей основной версии проекта.*

Answer (score 15):

Уже прошло два месяца автор наверняка не нуждается в помощи, но это возможно поможет тем кто ищет подобный ответ.
Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> 
Java Compiler: Project bytecode version: 6 
                Target bytecode version: 6 
    Попробуйте поменять на именно 6-ю версию, мне помогло!

Comment: Помогло! От себя добавлю: поменять нужно не именно на 6-ю версию, а на 6 либо выше: 7, 8, ...

Answer (score 7):

file->settings->search: Java Compiler -> Target bytecode version: 11

Comment: Пожалуйста, пишите более подробные ответы.

Comment: Спасибо! заработало

Answer (score 2):

```html
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1):

Из [официальной документации к компилятору](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/javac.html#GUID-AEEC9F07-CB49-4E96-8BC7-BCC2C7F725C9):

> Beginning with JDK 9, javac no longer supports -source release
>   settings less than or equal to 5. If settings less than or equal to 5
>   are used, then the javac command behaves as if -source 6 were
>   specified.

Так что, как уже правильно подсказали, нужно пройтись по настройкам (как самой IDE так и проекта) и проверить, что везде выставлены параметры language level и target bytecode version не ниже 6. А если в проекте используется сборщик, то и build-файл нужно проверить на наличие соответствующих параметров.

Answer (score 0):

Я проверила все настройки, какие нашла, добавила в pom.xml указание 14 версии, но это не помогло.
В моём случае проблема оказалась в файле ProjectName.iml, где было указано

```
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4" />
```

Я заменила 4 на 14, всё заработало.